# How to reference to a variable from onLoadFinished in onOptionsItemSelected?

Tags: java, android, variables, methods, menuitem

In this onLoadFinished method I get the content of a particular database column and set it on an EditView (mEditView), the id of which has been defined earlier in OnCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
    {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {           
        int textColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(NoteEntry.COLUMN_TEXT);

        String content = cursor.getString(textColumnIndex);
        mEditView.setText(content);         
        }
```

Now I need to use the variable "content" outside this method. For example, I write a method to make a toast message containing the "content" appear on the screen:

```
private void displayContent(String content) 
{
Toast.makeText(this, content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I want this toast to be displayed when an Actionbar menu button is clicked. But here a face a problem - when I include displayContent(String content) in OnOptionsItemSelected, I get an error because the variable "content" is not being recognized.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    switch(item.getItemId())
       {
        case R.id.display_toast:
            displayContent(String text);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);          
     }
```

Passing "String content" as second input to onOptionsItemSelected also doesn't solve the problem. I'm new to Android programming, and despite of spending a lot of time searching for a solution on the web I couldn't find an answer. So I would be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `displayContent(String text)` is basically creating a new variable text and then feeding that to the method, so it is empty. You have to save the variable as a global variable in your Activity, then you can access it in onOptionItemSelected. So it would be like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private String content;
```

then later in onLoadFinished you do not create a new variable you use that one

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
    {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {           
        int textColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(NoteEntry.COLUMN_TEXT);

        content = cursor.getString(textColumnIndex);
        mEditView.setText(content);         
        }
```

then in onOptionItemSelected you use content as a parameter of your method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    switch(item.getItemId())
       {
        case R.id.display_toast:
            displayContent(content);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);          
     }
```

Study up on the difference between local and global variables and this will make sense to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before posting this question, I've already tried to go the way you described  and created a local variable, but it doesn't work - the displayed toast is empty. But when the toast line is included in the onLoadFinished method, the toast pops up with the correct text in the app.

Comment: You should not create a local variable it needs to be global. It is important where you define the variable. If you define it in a method when you leave that method it goes away. Try defining the variable at the top of your activity outside any other methods.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. I mean, I created a GLOBAL variable, of course

Comment: Okay but did you still say `displayContent(String text)` when you called the method? because that creates a new variable called text with nothing in it. It should read `displayContent(content)`

Comment: First I tried to create a global variable and used displayContent(text). Since it didn't work, I started searching for information on the web and  tried this approach, because I couldn't find a corresponding answer. After your post I tried the first way (suggested by you too)  again, but it doesn't work.

Comment: That is strange. And they are in the same activity? Is this project on GitHub or anyplace i could see the rest of it or try to run it? My guess is that there is just a typo someplace that is preventing it from being saved.

Comment: Indeed, it was a typo! I wrote this part over a thousand times, but it just didn't work. Well, with your help I finally managed to solve this issue... Thank you very much!))

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer if it helped so more people can find it :)